# Identification of antenna parameters for calculation

Tags: antenna, design

Sorry if my question may seem simple, but I discover the plans of an antenna (RECTANGULAR COIL WITH MULTILAYER) and I can not identify *b* and *h* on this given schema,

```
Where:
x = width of coil
y = length of coil
b = width of cross section
h = height (coil build up) of cross section
```

[image]

Here are the three possibilities that I see,
The first one that seems to me to be the good one:
[image]

The second that could be as valid:
[image]

and finally the thirteenth which could be valid too but in this one there would be no 'depth' or thickness so I doubt that it is the right one:
[image]

Do the circles in the rectangle of the section represent wires ?

Where are *b* and *h* ?

What is the *direction* of *'coil build-up'* ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would probably help if you cite where you found this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably these dimensions are used to calculate the inductance by an approximation formular.

Wheeler's formular is likely used as it's often referenced when searching for such a respective approximation formular.

---

Then \$b\$ is:

[image]

And for \$h\$ you can think of printing that picture several times and placing the sheets one onto the other.

---

Here are also links of two sites applying wheeler's formular with isometric view pictures:

[http://www.rfcafe.com Multi-Layer Air-Core Inductance](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/inductance.htm)

- \$b \, @rfcafe \$ is \$h \, @your\,  picture\$
- \$c \, @rfcafe \$ is \$b \, @your \, picture\$

[www.allaboutcircuits.com](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/reference/chpt-1/inductor-sizing-equation/)

- \$l \, (length of coil) \, @allaboutcircuits \$ is \$h \, @your\,  picture\$
- \$c \, (thickness of coil)\, @allaboutcircuits \$ is \$b \, @your \, picture\$